# Form Field Into Url

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm new to this kind of stuff so sorry if this is not possible or does not make any sense. Im making a app where someone puts in there username into the form and when they press enter a popup says words but then i want for after they press ok it puts the username into the form ---- instagram://user?username --- where it says username thats where i want the username from the form to go then it will go there. sorry if this doesnt make sense or is not possible wondering if it is

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the value of the form field to `instagram:...` before submitting?

Comment: Yes, I am kind of confused, can you elaborate?

Comment: I have a form feild where they will enter there username and i when they click the button i want instagram://user?username to open up and where it says username for there username to go there

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your form action to GET. I believe that is what you are trying to ask.

```
<form action='[url submitting to]' method='GET'></form>
```

Comment: Yeah i want the url to be instagram://user?username BUT i want the username they entered into the form to go where it says username in the url

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, if this is the language you are working with, you could prevent the submit and get the username field and add it to url and load this page.

```
        //html
        <form>
           <input id="username">
        </form>

         //javascript 

         //the submit event is captured
         $('form').on('submit', function(e){

             //the event is passed in on the function and is used to prevent the 
             //default action so we can perform some further action
             e.preventDefault();

             //here we grab the value of the the #username text field
             var user = $('input#username').val();

             //here we are loading the instagram page based upon the user's textfield 
             window.location = 'instagram://user?' + user;
         });
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This kinda seems like what i need just dont know how to make it work

Comment: Are you looking to load an instagram user's page based upon their username?

Comment: yeah but instagram://user?username  is instagrams iphone hook is what im using. and where it says username is where there username goes.

Comment: So from Safari, you are looking to open up the iPhone application with the user's name attached?

Comment: YES!So when they press submit it will open there instagram

Comment: Ok, well it would work just like a normal web page, you write you HTML/CSS/JavaScript, add it to your server and use it via mobile or desktop browser.

Comment: I dont quite know how to do that i know how to make a form and everything dont know how to use javascript i added it but its not doing anything

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to get started with jQuery  http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#jQuery:_The_Basics

Comment: Still dont get it i put it in a .js file but i dont get anything